# Is it ok to create databases in AWS RDS dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a new database so that I can transfer my application to AWS without much work. According to this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html) I should do this to connect to a RDS Database:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
$_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'],
$_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'],
$_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME'],
$_SERVER['RDS_PORT']);
```

It works, so I tried adding a new database and made a new connection + query using the new database and it also worked.

My question is, the database name from the link, is fetch from `$_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME']`, I do not know if there is any `AWS` dependent thing with them adding the db details to `$_SERVER` variable.

So is it safe if I create a new database **dynamically** using php? I am wondering if tomorrow morning their system will suddenly drop my new database because it was created outside `RDS`?

The AWS Server (EC2, RDS, etc.) were set up by `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`, I didn't set them up manually so I am having those `am I allowed to do this situations`

Answer (score 0):

in your situation database will only drop when RDS will be rebuild otherwise its fine, even before rebuild it will ask final snapshot. My personal suggestion is if you want multiple databases on the RDS , create the manually not with Elastic beanstalk